# FindPeaks finds Minima, but not all of them

Tags: list-manipulation, peak-detection

I have 10 sets of data, which are the result of measuring the way of a mass falling down over time, bringing a wheel into rotation when the mass hits the ground and then the wheel lifts the mass up again and so on. I want to determine the friction out of the procentual height-loss.

So my idea was to Import the 10 lists of data and I named them
`Reihe1` - `Reihe10`.

Now I need to find the local minima (which are the points that I need to determine the height of the mass):

```
peaks1 = FindPeaks[Reihe1[[All, 2]]]
peaks2 = FindPeaks[Reihe2[[All, 2]]]
peaks3 = FindPeaks[Reihe3[[All, 2]]]
peaks4 = FindPeaks[Reihe4[[All, 2]]]
peaks5 = FindPeaks[Reihe5[[All, 2]]]
peaks6 = FindPeaks[Reihe6[[All, 2]]]
peaks7 = FindPeaks[Reihe7[[All, 2]]]
peaks8 = FindPeaks[Reihe8[[All, 2]]]
peaks9 = FindPeaks[Reihe9[[All, 2]]]
peaks10 = FindPeaks[Reihe10[[All, 2]]]
ListLinePlot[Reihe1[[All, 2]], 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[peaks1]}
 ]
ListLinePlot[Reihe2[[All, 2]], 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[peaks2]}
 ]
ListLinePlot[Reihe3[[All, 2]], 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[peaks3]}
 ]
ListLinePlot[Reihe4[[All, 2]], 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[peaks4]}
 ]
ListLinePlot[Reihe5[[All, 2]], 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[peaks5]}
 ]
ListLinePlot[Reihe6[[All, 2]], 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[peaks6]}
 ]
ListLinePlot[Reihe7[[All, 2]], 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[peaks7]}
 ]
ListLinePlot[Reihe8[[All, 2]], 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[peaks8]}
 ]
ListLinePlot[Reihe9[[All, 2]], 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[peaks9]}
 ]
ListLinePlot[Reihe10[[All, 2]], 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[peaks10]}
 ]
```

This sometimes works:

[image: workingg example]

sometimes it works only for some peaks:

[image: half-working example, some minima missing]

sometimes it finds maxima and minima:

[image: not working example: maxima and minima]

What I don't understand is, although the 10 data-lists are almost the same, *Mathematica* seems to have trouble  finding those peaks. Is there a better way to find the minima?

I also wonder why this function finds the minima, although the description says it finds maxima. I guess this is why I sometimes get maxima, too.

I would also like to get the x-values for the minimax, so I can plot them together with the original data. I have, on the x-axis, the number of the value, not its time because `FindPeaks` gives me the `y`-value, but not the `x`-value. But what I really need is a function that extracts the `y`-values of those local minima.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the data you are using?
I tries with something similar but I cannot reproduce your error.
Also keep in mind that FindPeaks accepts a scale parameter thus some of the peaks may be suppressed.

Comment: @Batracos Thank you, here is a link to one of the datasets [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l1uvx7r2t0bx4u6/sampledata.csv?dl=0)

Comment: @Rudolph: The dataset you linked has no data in.

Comment: `FindPeaks` finds maxima, not minima.  Are you sure you are showing the actual code you used?